# Partial ordered Comparator

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

How to implement `java.util.Comparator` that orders its elements according to a partial order relation?

For example given a partial order relation *a* ≺ *c*, *b* ≺ *c*; the order of *a* and *b* is undefined.

Since `Comparator` requires a total ordering, the implementation orders elements for which the partial ordering is undefined arbitrarily but consistent.

Would the following work?

```
interface Item {
    boolean before(Item other);
}

class ItemPartialOrderComperator implements Comparator<Item> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {
        if(o1.equals(o2)) {  // Comparator returns 0 if and only if o1 and o2 are equal;
            return 0;
        }
        if(o1.before(o2)) {
            return -1;
        }
        if(o2.before(o1)) {
            return +1;
        }
        return o1.hashCode() - o2.hashCode(); // Arbitrary order on hashcode
    }
}
```

- Is this comparator's ordering transitive?
  *(I fear that it is not)*
- Are `Comparators` required to be transitive?
  *(when used in a `TreeMap`)*
- How to implement it correctly?
  *(if the implementation above doesn't work)

  (Hashcodes can collide, for simplicity collisions the example ignores collisions; see [Damien B's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28494/814206) to [Impose a total ordering on all instances of *any* class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301/impose-a-total-ordering-on-all-instances-of-any-class-in-java) for a fail-safe ordering on hashcodes.)*

Comment: *Is this comparator's ordering transitive?* => in your example, transitivity would imply a < b, which you say is not true.

Comment: Is this comparator's ordering transitive? That depends on how your before method is implemented

Comment: _Is this comparator's ordering transitive?_ I think it is transitive if and only if `hashCode()` is monotonic with respect to the partial ordering. Which it almost certainly isn't.

Comment: If `a.before(b)`, but `a.hashCode() > b.hashCode()`, and you have a `c` that isn't comparable to `a` nor `b` by `before` with `b.hashCode() < c.hashCode() < a.hashCode()`, then `compare` says that `b < c`, and `c < a`, but `a < b`.

Comment: All - an example of partial ordering where I believe I faced a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54855025/merge-n-lists-and-sort-data-maintaining-original-order-constraint

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that, when you have incomparable elements, you need to fall back to something cleverer than comparing hash codes. For example, given a partial order {a < b, c < d}, the hash codes could satisfy h(d) < h(b) < h(c) < h(a), which means that a < b **<** c < d **<** a (**bold** denotes tie broken by hash code), which will cause problems with a `TreeMap`.

In general, there's probably nothing for you to do except topologically sort the keys beforehand, so some details about the partial orders of interest to you would be welcome.

Comment: Detail: case is Http (REST) servlet content negotiation, match specific media types (e.g. 'text/html') before more general type (e.g. 'text/*' and '*/*').  So in this case comparing 'type is star', 'subtype is star', 'comparator on type', 'comparator on subtype' solves the problem.

Comment: You might find https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9949 interesting: I once implemented content negotiation with a partial ordering (though unfortunately this code never made it into Spring :S )

Comment: I am currently implementing code that leverages Guava graphs to determine indirect dependencies. The principle is: if two items can be compared, return accordingly. In any case, put them into a knowledge graph and for nodes that are not comparable search the graph for a connection. The idea seems to be standing, but I am facing currently tweaking the code. Unfortunately it requires memory and may not be scalable. I'll give you a gist just in case

Answer (score 8):

It seems to be more of an answer than a comment so I'll post it

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) says:

> It follows immediately from the contract for compare that the quotient is an equivalence relation on S, and that the imposed ordering is a total order on S."

So no, a Comparator requires a total ordering. If you implement this with a partial ordering you're breaching the interface contract.

Even if it might work in some scenario, you should *not* attempt to solve your problem in a way that breaches the contract of the interface.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362819/java-partially-ordered-collectione) about data structures that do fit a partial ordering.

Answer (score 2):

Any time I've tried using hash codes for this sort of thing I've come to regret it. You will be much happier if your ordering is deterministic - for debuggability if nothing else. The following will achieve that, by creating a fresh index for any not previously encountered `Item` and using those indices for the comparison if all else fails.

Note that the ordering still is not guaranteed to be transitive.

```
class ItemPartialOrderComperator implements Comparator<Item> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {
        if(o1.equals(o2)) {
            return 0;
        }
        if(o1.before(o2)) {
            return -1;
        }
        if(o2.before(o1)) {
            return +1;
        }
        return getIndex(o1) - getIndex(o2);
    }

    private int getIndex(Item i) {
        Integer result = indexMap.get(i);
        if (result == null) {
            indexMap.put(i, result = indexMap.size());
        }
        return result;
    }

    private Map<Item,Integer> indexMap = new HashMap<Item, Integer>();
}
```

Comment: **This implementation is buggy and may lead to an IllegalArgumentException**, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31970508/partial-ordered-comparator-to-total-ordered-comparator for the details.

Comment: @blubb you're right, that's pretty much what I meant when I said it's not guaranteed to be transitive. My solution was only meant to improve upon the use of hashcodes.

Answer (score 1):

In jdk7, your object will throw runtime exception :

> Area: API: Utilities
>       Synopsis: Updated sort behavior for Arrays and Collections may throw an *IllegalArgumentException*
>       Description: The sorting algorithm used by `java.util.Arrays.sort` and (indirectly) by `java.util.Collections.sort` has been replaced.
>  The
>   new sort implementation may throw an *IllegalArgumentException* if it
>   detects a Comparable that violates the Comparable contract. The
>   previous implementation silently ignored such a situation.
>       If the previous behavior is desired, you can use the new system property, `java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort`, to restore previous
>   mergesort behavior.
>       Nature of Incompatibility: behavioral
>       RFE: **6804124**

Answer (score 0):

If `a < b` and `b < c` implies `a < c`, then you have made a total ordering by using the hashCodes. Take `a < d, d < c`. The partial order says that `b` and `d` not necessarily are ordered. By introducing hashCodes you provide an ordering.

Example: is-a-descendant-of(human, human).

```
Adam (hash 42) < Moses (hash 17), Adam < Joe (hash 9)
```

Implies

```
Adam < Joe < Moses
```

A negative example would be the same relation, but when time travel allows being your own descendant.

Answer (score -1):

When one item is neither "before" nor "after" another, instead of returning a comparison of the hashcode, just return `0`. The result will be "total ordering" and "arbitrary" ordering of  coincident items.

Comment: But he won't be able to store two of those objects in a TreeMap!!

Comment: Breach of contract. Say `a < b`, and `c` isn't comparable to either. `compare(a,c) = 0` and `compare (b,c) = 0` according to this, but that requires `compare(a,b) = 0`.

Comment: Isn't that still a violation of the interface specifications?  I think a partial ordering of any kind is a problem when used with Comparable.

Comment: "The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive: `((compare(x, y)>0) && (compare(y, z)>0))` implies `compare(x, z)>0`." http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM this answer is transitive if *neither "before" nor "after"* is transitive. My answer is just saying to not break ties using hashcode - if they have the same ordering, return 0.